# Kill Mathjax Queue

Tags: mathjax

I am writing a web app with angular and am trying to include mathjax. What's quite annoying, is that mathjax doesn't stop to render (i.e. typesetting math) when I navigate from one view/page/route/whatever to the next. Question: How can I kill the mathjax queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to render each element of the queue after another. That way you wouldn't have to kill the queue.